# MySQL Column Year Parsing and Sorting

Tags: mysql

I have one table, I want to sort by years. However, we have a problem.

The column is in text format. Because it is in the years before Christ.

First I need to list the years before Christ and then the present years.

Table: date_events

| event_year | event_title |
| --- | --- |
| B.C 405 | example |
| B.C 406 | example |
| 2022 | example |

Comment: You have only `B.C` or `A.C` ,too ?

Comment: B.C 44, 959, 1000, 1994, 2022...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `order by` the column `event_year`, but replacing `'B.C '` by a minus sign `'-'`, and converting it to a `signed`:

```
select *
from date_events
order by cast(replace(event_year, 'B.C ', '-') as signed);
```

Output:

| event_year | event_title |
| --- | --- |
| B.C 406 | example |
| B.C 405 | example |
| 2022 | example |

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/342aad/2)

Comment: Thank you, but there is an error in ordering in normal years, how can I solve this situation?

959
96
1996

Comment: @Smurfnetwork seems to work fine! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0eceb/1

Comment: The only difference is that your column is varchar and mine is text.

Is it caused by this?

Comment: @Smurfnetwork not really: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f4a9ba/1

Comment: There is a sequencing error. You can see that the year 406 is listed before 405.

Comment: @Smurfnetwork yes, 406 B.C comes *before* 405 B.C!